# Work items commits state control

Tags: git, tfs, version-control

I am using `git` under TFS, and I was associating commits to work items through `#work-item` i.e:

```
git commit -m "fix #123"
```

Now I want to be able to change its status with something like:

```
git commit -m "Changed foo function. closed #125"
```

But it did not work. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any way to achieve this feature for now. There is already a feature request submitted on User Voice , you can vote it: [Update work items on commit for git](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/6380299-update-work-items-on-commit-for-git).

Answer (score 0):

For some months this feature ist implemented, but has to be activated separately.

Then using the keyword `fix`, `fixes` or `fixed #ID` will close the workitem.

Detailed instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/devops/repos/git/resolution-mentions?view=azure-devops

Answer (score -1):

Ah so I am not familiar with TFS but you are trying to commit again and assuming there were no changes, and even if there were you would need to stage them first with

```
    git add <filename>
```

you cannot commit again if there were no changes

however if you are just trying to change the previous commit message you can use

```
    git commit --amend
```

source: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-commit-message/

however I don't think this is the correct method for what you want to do. I doubt any system would have changing commit messages as part of its process I would advise you investigate your system and it's requirements.

Comment: This does not answer the question -- it's not a question about committing to Git repositories, it's a question about changing the state of TFS work items as part of a commit.