# Azure DevOps - How to change state of work item via git commit

Tags: git, azure-devops

I want to know if there have any methods can change the state of work item via git commit automatically, I had been surveyed this question but I wasn't getting any answer that I needed.

I already tried the git commit with Fixes bug #123, Resolves bug #123 or Closes bug #123, but that only link the commit to the work item development and never changes the state.

THANKS

Comment: A commit doesn't mean that a work item is complete. The usual pattern is for a work item's state to be closed when the commit is **merged**, which can happen via pull request.

Comment: The defined work item transitions can also mess with this -- if there's no transition defined directly between the current and target states (as is the case with our organisation) then even setting the flag to close the item when completing the pull request won't have the desired effect.

Comment: I see. I think another way to solve the question of changing the state of work items automatically is to edit the Pipeline's flow that checks the work item after testing succeeded. Thanks to both of you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have known that changing the state of the work item **via git commit** is not feasible in azure devops through the survey and the comments reply given above .

These similar cases([Close a work item via the commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36469543/close-a-work-item-via-the-commit-message) ; [Work items commits state control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679147/work-items-commits-state-control)) can be used as a reference.

The previous user voice site is not currently active. You could choose to submit a new one to our main [forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) for product suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I've been following this issue for some years by now and finally they implemented this with one type of keywords:

Using the keyword `fix`, `fixes` or `fixed #ID` will close the workitem.

Detailed instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/repos/git/resolution-mentions?view=azure-devops